# how to create a dynamic sql statement w/ python and mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following code:

```
    def sql_exec(self, sql_stmt, args = tuple()):
        """
        Executes an SQL statement and returns a cursor.

        An SQL exception might be raised on error

        @return: SQL cursor object
        """
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        if self.__debug_sql:
            try:
                print "sql_exec: " % (sql_stmt % args)
            except:
                print "sql_exec: " % sql_stmt

        cursor.execute(sql_stmt, args)
        return cursor

    def test(self, limit = 0):
        result = sql_exec("""
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                table
            """ + ("LIMIT %s" if limit else ""), (limit, ))
        while True:
            row = result.fetchone()
            if not row:
                break
            print row
        result.close()
```

How can I nicely write test() so it works with or without 'limit' without having to write two queries?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't.

Do not build SQL "on the fly".  It's a security nightmare.  It will cause more problems than it appears to solve.

Second, read the MySQL page on `LIMIT`.  They suggest using a large number.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 18446744073709551615;
```

Switch your default from 0 to 18446744073709551615.

If you don't like that, then use an `if` statement and write two versions of the SELECT.  It's better in the long run to have two similar SELECT statements with no security hole.

Third, don't test this way.

Use `unittest`.  http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html

Comment: Thanks S.Lott,

I am aware of the security nightmare (SQL injections and what not) that might happen if I build my own SQL but having two identical queries is maintenance hassle.

The LIMIT suggestion is nice. As for unittest, I got to set some time to learn how to use it, seems useful.

Thanks,
Elias

Comment: @lallous: "having two identical queries is maintenance hassle".  Not really.  The SQL Injection threat is a hassle.  Two identical queries is hardly worth comparing with the potential liability of hacked data.